# Include plots inside a dataframe

Tags: r

I am reading an excel file into a dataframe, I have originally 13 columns and 57 rows, using read.xslx I get 12 columns with my data however column 13 is ignored and not read as it is not numeric or text it is jpg plots. How can I read them in a dataframe or R table?

Comment: I'm not sure you can import it directly in your R dataframe since it is an image and dataframes are made of letters and numbers.

Comment: Same conclusion that I got, so let me get one step back these images were produced with ggplot in R too, can I save those 57 images in a list/vector/matric to visualize them in an interactive heatmap ? that my goal, visualize plots of 57 data entities in an interactive heatmap ...... i already did my interactive heatmap but ofcourse I can only see in the interaction the 12 column but never the plots as they are missing from my dataframe

Comment: I know that you can combine multiple plot inside one (see this link for reference : https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html or with ggplot2 http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/) but I'm quite not sure it could work on an interactive heatmap. I'll take a look in some of my packages.

Comment: I can show you an example of my script, for sure you will have an idea how can i include it :

Comment: p <- ggplot(Hdf,
       aes(x = analysis, y = Drug.Name, fill = DSS, label = Slope, label2 = IC50)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_label(fill = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "Blue", limits=range(Hdf$DSS))+
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0), label=abbreviate)+
  geom_text_repel()+
  coord_quickmap()+
  coord_cartesian()

Comment: the label is my interactive variable, so the slope and IC50 are numbers in my dataframe and I can view them interactively, if I just know how can i add a list of plot like a column or define them as a label, it will be done... I also have those plots in a workbook of openxslx package but have no idea how to define them inside this script

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the best approach would be to not store the .jpg file in the excel but instead store the path to it. That way R can read it as a string column and you can latter apply a function to read all the .jpg with thoese specified paths.

Comment: thank you so much for this suggestion I think it might work.

Comment: Glad I could help!